# JPA search child class

Tags: jpa

In the JPA, how to write a query to load child class. For example, I need a query to load paymentSet which contains CashPayment if any, CheckPayment if any .

Thanks.

```
class SalesOrder {
  Set<Payment> paymentSet;
}
class Payment {};
class CashPayment extends Payment;
class CheckPayment extends Payment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you solve this problem depends on how you've modeled your database. The [wikibooks page on JPA Inheritance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) is pretty good for seeing what options are available. One option is to store all `Payment`s in the same table, but provide a [`@DiscriminatorValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorValue.html) to indicate which concrete class should be loaded. For example:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PAYMENT_TYPE")
@Table(name="PAYMENT")
class Payment {
  @Id
  private long id;
  //...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CASH")
class CashPayment extends Payment {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CHECK")
class CheckPayment extends Payment {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the inheritance relationship. I refer to the documentation: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/. You can also browse through the stackoverflow questions related to 'jpa inheritance'.